# How to solve the TypeError problem in the pandas.pivot_table method?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, data-analysis

My data is a DataFrame named **interval_data**.
The **duration** and **amplitude** columns specify a range.

```
|     | duration     | amplitude         | frequency | density  |
|-----|--------------|-------------------|-----------|----------|
| 0   | (1.0, 5.192] | (-11.42, -11.08]  | 1         | 0.007299 |
| 1   | (1.0, 5.192] | (-10.057, -9.716] | 2         | 0.014599 |
| 2   | (1.0, 5.192] | (-8.352, -8.011]  | 4         | 0.029197 |
| 3   | (1.0, 5.192] | (-6.307, -5.966]  | 2         | 0.014599 |
| 4   | (1.0, 5.192] | (-5.284, -4.943]  | 2         | 0.014599 |
| ... | ...          | ...               | ...       | ...      |
```

I want to create a pivot table from the data. 
I'm getting a TypeError like the following:

```py
>>> pd.pivot_table(interval_data, values='density', index='duration', columns='amplitude')
Out[]: TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Column types are as follows:

```py
>>> type(interval_data.duration[0])
Out[]: pandas._libs.interval.Interval
>>> type(interval_data.density[0])
Out[]: numpy.float64
```

Index and column have to specify a range.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: With above data sample, it is working at my end. Please check your whole dataset.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Another example: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DmCMksZnXs/

Comment: Which pandas version are you using ? Your code works in pandas 0.23.1

Comment: I'm using 0.24.2